# VLOOKUP is returning blank as 1/0/1990, rather than nothing visible

Tags: excel, date, formatting, string-formatting, vlookup

All cells are formatted for dates, when a cell is blank I would like it to return an apparently blank cell rather than `1/0/1900`.  Here is what I have so far however It is still returning the date instead of a blank:

```
= IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($B$4,TrainingDatabase!$A$3:$S$14,3,0))=  0,"", (VLOOKUP($B$4,TrainingDatabase!$A$3:$S$14,3,0)))
```

Comment: You might be able to let the cells display as blanks without adding any functions to the cells. Just look out for some other format options available.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?  The information are all dates for training courses so I cant display them as number or text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try formatting as:

```
mm/dd/yyyy;;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please delete `=0` from your formula

Or use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$4,TrainingDatabase!$A$3:$S$14,3,0),"")
```

Edit#4: The question is how to replace **blanks** not N/A so the answer should be:

```
= IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP($B$4,TrainingDatabase!$A$3:$S$14,3,0)),"", (VLOOKUP($B$4,TrainingDatabase!$A$3:$S$14,3,0)))
```

Comment: That is how I originally had it and it still displays the same, I was searching for possible solutions and that was one that was displayed.

Comment: @Axios_Andrew I have updated the answer, does the second solution work for you?

Comment: @Axios_Andrew sorry, the `IF` statement was redundant, please try again

Comment: Still seeing the same thing, I know these fixes have worked for me in the past when it is formatted as text or number, is it just the fact that it is formatted as short date that is causing this?  I really need them formatted as date unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71828/discussion-between-user3964075-and-axios-andrew).

Comment: Of course pnuts solution works but if you wanted to alter the formula to return an actual blank instead of a formatted zero you could use this version `=IFERROR(1/(1/VLOOKUP($B$4,TrainingDatabase!$A$3:$S$14,3,0)),"")`

Answer (score 0):

please try this formula :

```
= IF(VLOOKUP($B$4,TrainingDatabase!$A$3:$S$14,3,0)=0,"", (VLOOKUP($B$4,TrainingDatabase!$A$3:$S$14,3,0)))
```